# Llenar valores de una prompt con selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de pruebas de automatización con selenium, estoy tratando de llenar unos campos de texto que aparecen en alert tipo prompt.

[image: Campos Requeridos]

Pero no logro hacer que se auto llenen los campos, aqui les dejo mi codigo

```
enter code here
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd

# Opciones de navegación
options =  webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
#salta los certificados de ssl
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
#deshabilita las extenciones
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')


driver_path = 'C://Users//User//Downloads//chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)

# inizializamos el navegador

driver.get('https://54.172.126.24:8000/status')

#WebDriverWait(driver, 40)\
#    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
#                                     'button.secondary-button.small-link')))\
#    .click()
time.sleep(3)
n1 = driver.find_element_by_id('n1')
n1.send_keys("dasdad")

#login_password = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("password")
```

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/alerts/

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

Selenium cuenta con unas funcionalidades para trabajar en esa alerta

Te dejo el link: https://learntutorials.net/es/selenium-webdriver/topic/6048/manejar-una-alerta

Tienes que hacer un senkeys si quieres añadir el user y la clave y luego usar el alert.accept()

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, he modificado el codigo pero no me rellena el campo que necesito:

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
import time
 import pandas as pd

 # Opciones de navegación
 options =  webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
 #salta los certificados de ssl
 options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
 options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
 #deshabilita las extenciones
 options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')


 driver_path = 'C://Users//User//Downloads//chromedriver.exe'

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)

 # inizializamos el navegador


  
 driver.get('file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/selenium/p1/ejercicios.html')


 driver.find_element(By.ID, "btn").click()

 alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)\
    .until(EC.alert_is_present())\

 alert.send_keys('Some text to send')


 alert.dismiss()
```

Comment: y esto que hace?

Comment: El codigo lo que hace es abrir una ventana prompt, y necesito rellenar ese prompt con un texto especifivco